# What is the number of bytes that letter A will occupy in UTF-16?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a really simple question actually, what is the minimum size (number of bytes) that letter "A" is supposed to occupy in UTF-16 encoding when coding in Java (this should be irrelevant though).

I really thought this one was pretty simple: since UTF-16 is either 2 or 4 bytes, and letter A is well a "simple" one, the answer should be two, but then:

```
System.out.println("A".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length); // prints 1, as expected
System.out.println("A".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16).length); // prints 4, I thought it would be 2

System.out.println("AB".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);// prints 2 as expected
System.out.println("AB".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16).length); // prints 6, expected 4
```

Can someone bring some light here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use UTF-16 it needs to define whether it is little endian or big endian.  It does with with a BOM or `\uFEFF` or `\uFFFE` which two extra bytes at the start.

UTF-8 is one byte at a time so there is no byte order to keep track of.

If you use UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE it defines the order so it shouldn't need the BOM

Comment: To spell this out: The BOM takes 2 bytes (like any BMP code point), so the length of "A" is  2 + 2 and the length of "AB" is 2 + 2 + 2. Generally, the length of UTF-16 encoded string of *n* BMP characters is 2 + 2 × *n*.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that makes sense, stupid me. But why does UTF-16 requires BOM and UTF-8 does not?